# Why is `onversionchange` never called in Chrome 27?

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, indexeddb, google-chrome-app

When I try to upgrade the database, despite a `IDBVersionChangeEvent` event being thrown (it gets sent to my `onupgrade` callback), `onversionchange` is never called! This leads to me having a `blocked` event. I can't figure out how to get it to call the right handler.

**Using Chrome 27**

```
//Account for different names of indexedDB
window.indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB;

//Account for different names of transaction and key range
window.IDBTransaction = window.IDBTransaction || window.webkitIDBTransaction || window.msIDBTransaction;
window.IDBKeyRange = window.IDBKeyRange || window.webkitIDBKeyRange || window.msIDBKeyRange;

var req = indexedDB.open( "test6", 2 );
req.onupgradeneeded = function(event)
{
    console.log( "This upgrade gets called" ); 

    //These do nothing
    event.target.onversionchange = function(event) { console.log( "request version change" ); };
    event.target.result.onversionchange = function(event) { console.log( "database version change" ); };
};

req.onsuccess = function(event)
{
    console.log( "This Success is called" ); 

    //These do nothing
    event.target.onversionchange = function(event) { console.log( "request version change" ); };
    event.target.result.onversionchange = function(event) { console.log( "database version change" ); };
};

req.onerror = function(event)
{
    console.log( "This error is not called" ); 
};

req.onblocked = function(event)
{
    console.log( "This blocked is sometimes called" ); 
};

//This also does nothing
req.onversionchange = function(event) { console.log( "request version change" ); };
```

I've tried adding it everywhere and it never gets called!

**EDIT (not solved)** It appears `indexedDB.deleteDatabase()` calls the onversionchange handler! Not sure why that does but the upgrade does not.

Answer (score 2):

`onversionchange` event is [dispatched by database](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#database-interface) instance. So you should listen like this

```
req.onsuccess = function(e) {
  db = e.target.result;
  db.onversionchange = function(e) {
     db.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: doesn't work. it still never fires. if you look at my code, you'll see I was already doing that.

Comment: have your call `db.close()` ? before testing, close all your browser instance and make sure no software update pending.

Comment: can you test the code above? does `onversionchange` get called for you?

Comment: Don, it will NOT be called. you are listening to wrong object. as i said, you mist listen to database object.

Comment: Please look at my code again. Do you see where I have `event.target.result.onversionchange = function(event) { console.log( "database version change" ); };`? That is listening to the database. Still does not get called.

Comment: I hear you but, can you please try my code in Chrome and let me know if it calls it for you?

Answer (score 1):

A versionchange event is fired at the database when a different request tries to increment the version. So, if you add to the bottom of your code above

```
var req2 = indexedDB.open( "test6", 3 ); // <- note: "3"
req2.onblocked = function(e) { console.log("this will be called"); };
req2.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {
    console.log("this will be called once the first connection is closed");
};
```

Your original versionchange event handler should be called, though I didn't test it myself.

Edit: It works for me on chrome 28.0.1500.45 beta:

```
<script>

var req = indexedDB.open( "test6", 2 );

req.onsuccess = function(event)
{
    console.log( "This Success is called" ); 

    //These do nothing
    event.target.onversionchange = function(event) { console.log( "request version change 2" ); };
    event.target.result.onversionchange = function(event) { console.log( "database version change 2" ); };
};

req.onerror = function(event)
{
    console.log( "This error is not called" ); 
};

req.onblocked = function(event)
{
    console.log( "This blocked is sometimes called" ); 
};

var req2 = indexedDB.open( "test6", 3 ); // <- note: "3"
req2.onblocked = function(e) { console.log("this blocked will be called"); };
req2.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {
    console.log("this will be called once the first connection is closed");
};

</script>
```

gives

```
This Success is called dogs.html:7
database version change 2 dogs.html:11
this blocked will be called dogs.html:25
```

Comment: Can you please try this in chrome? It still never fires `db.onversionchange`. It does call `db.onupgradeneeded` but not `onversionchange`.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that `onblocked` fires most likely means that you have a db connection open somewhere else, probably in another tab.

The `onversionchange` event fires in that other tab (or possibly many tabs).

You need to listen for the `onversionchange` event on the db connection object there, and handle it there. For example, you could close the db connection there, and display a dialog box instructing the user that they should reload the page to get the new db version.

Do something like this:

```
  req.onsuccess = function(event)
  {
      var db = event.target.result
      db.onversionchange = function(event) { 
        document.body.innerHTML = "" // or a more subtle way to disable the page
        db.close()
        window.alert("please reload the page for the latest version")
      }
  };
```

I haven't worked closely with IndexedDB recently, but I think I remember that `onblocked` fires regardless of whether the other active db connections have an onversionchange listener which closes the db. I think you'll always get `onblocked` first, and if/when all connections have been closed you'll get the `onsuccess` event, allowing you to work with the new db.

The reason you see the `onversionchange` event fire when you do `indexedDB.deleteDatabase()` is that you attempt to delete the database while you have opened a connection in that tab.

Comment: I don't have another tab. It's a hosted/packaged app. And it only has one instance. I agree that somewhere the db is opened and not closed, but no where do I get that notification. And the only place I open is in that hosted app's only instance. That is why I'm stumped.